# Query to find the newly created change number in service now

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, servicenow

Here is the requirement. Where I have release pipeline stage in azure devops to create change ticket in service now then I have enabled gates in next stage (using ServiceNow management) where I have to use this newly created service now change ticket, as gate success criteria is specific change number should exist. I'm looking for the query to fetch the newly created change ticket in service now.

Comment: I am also looking for something similar solution but no luck till now.